# How to make a copy of a temp raster in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, saga, copy

I have a temp raster (SAGA raster) file. How can I make a copy of this file (like "save as")?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you cant find the temp file...

I've several times simply run the raster calculator on the temp-file to result in zero difference like "x >=0 OR x <=0" ;-)
This multiplied (cause always 1) with you temp-file will give you a raster you can save.

Answer (score 3):

Normally the files created by SEXTANTE toolsets like SAGA are saved temporarily somewhere. Click on the raster and look in the options/metadata.

In the QGIS Master version (1.9) there is also the option to save the raster via "save-as" if you rightclick on the rasterlayer.

But you could also simply use the gdal-tools like this (without prior testing):
-> Just use the gdal tools with standard-options. For example make a reprojection with the current proj4.